# QuillJS : Add info in a text

Tags: quill

Thank you for your interest in my question.

**Technology used :** PHP / JS

**Wish result :** I would like to be able to inject into the editor a sort of information pointer.

I was inspired by the Multiple Cursors version 1.3 of Quilljs (Link: https://quilljs.com/0.20/docs/modules/multi-cursors/).

I would like to be able to give a position, a color and an information text to display in the editor. 
These pointers of information should not disturb the writing and should not be included in the recovery of the text with `quill.getContents();`

**See image :**

[image: See image :]

**Question :** Would anyone have an idea of how I should go about it?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: I researched the problem a bit. The problem is that it would probably require writing a whole module that does what you want. I'm not sure if anyone is going to do it in an answer here on SO.

Comment: I did not have a big hope, but I thought that a person would have already built this kind of plugin. Anyway I would provide the module if I develop :)

Comment: Quill maintainer keeps list of plugins check it https://github.com/quilljs/awesome-quill

Comment: I would call this a "comment" feature. I tried the [quill-comment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-comment) module, but it was pretty incomplete.

Comment: Your testimony is very interesting, indeed it is incomplete but it is a road to the solutions

Comment: You might have to create your own blot type, witch just insert a marker and an id into your Quill text. Then on these specific markers, render with absolute position your comments ( `const bounds = this.quill.getBounds(marker.index)` bounds would you give you X and Y coord for rendering, like it is used with Quill Multiple Cursor).